# i want to get data between specified dates with start time and end time. SQL QUERY is required

Tags: ms-access

I am using fields `logdate`, `logtime` and `loggeddata` in an `MS Access table`. In this table logged data will be updated with date and time. From this table i want to get data between specified dates with start time and end time. I have written query like

```
Select * from LogDataTable 
where (LogDate >= DateValue('" & FromDTP.Value & "') 
  and Logtime >= TimeValue('" & FromTime.Value & "')) 
  and (LogDate<=DateValue('" & ToDTP.Value & "') 
  and LogTime <= TimeValue('" & ToTime.Value & "'))"
```

Issue is i am getting only one date data not like expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the date/time values and format to string expressions:

```
"select * from LogDataTable where 
    LogDate + LogTime >= #" & Format(DateValue(FromDTP.Value) + TimeValue(FromTime.Value), "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#
    and 
    LogDate + LogTime <= #" & Format(DateValue(ToDTP.Value) + TimeValue(ToTime.Value), "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"
```